# axios POST запрос с кириллицей на windows-1251

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Пытаюсь отправить запрос на сайт с windows-1251, отправляя кириллицу и получить cookies, но не выходит, в чем моя проблема? Можно заменить axios, но цель - получить cookies после POST запроса на сайт с windows-1251 и передавая в параметре кириллицу

```js
var surname = iconv.encode('Иванов', 'win1251')
var pass = '123456'

const requestBody = {
    surname: surname,
    pass: pass
}

const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
}

url = "https://example.com/auth"
axios.post(url, qs.stringify(requestBody), config)
  .then((result) => {
      console.log(result)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

Comment: Таки в чём конкретно проблема?

Comment: @AlexeyTen , в том что запрос уходит, но авторизация не проходит, как я понимаю, если сайт на 1251, то и кириллицу, которую отправляем нужно кодировать в 1251, как в коде, вроде и хедеры правильные стоят, но авторизация не проходит, неправильный логин или пароль.

Comment: Не проще ли для начала посмотреть что там браузер отсылает?

Comment: Сайт может проверять авторизационный билет через куки, прислушайтесь к совету, откройте браузер хром или фокс, нажмите F12, выберите "сеть", сделайте авторизационный запрос, внимательно почитайте "Заголовки запроса". Что может не хватать. Например в `headers` нужно добавить `Reffer: ваш сайт`, `Cookie` и т п. Кирилицу задаёт сервер, а не клиент, её указывать не нужно.

Comment: Ещё стандартные движки проверяют наличие полей в `headers` таких: `Host`, `User-Agent`.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. При чём тут вообще куки?

Comment: @Qwertiy некоторые хосты могут через куки выдавать билет, что б проверить робот или нет, в данном случае уже вижу что не в этом дело.

Comment: @nick_n_a, вообще-то это автору вопроса был вопрос...

Answer (score 0):

`qs.stringify` работает, как мне известно, только с UTF-8. Поэтому нужно просто сделать свою версию `qs.stringify`, которая по пути будет ещё и переводить значения в Windows-1251.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import FormData from 'form-data';
import iconv from 'iconv-lite';

// Функция энкодинга строк в win1251
const encodeToWin1251 = (str) => {
  return str.replace(/ /g, '+').replace(/(.)/g, (substr) => {
    if (/[а-яА-ЯЇїІіЄєҐґ`]/.test(substr)) {
      return iconv.encode(substr, 'win1251').toString('hex').toUpperCase().replace(/(..)/g, '%$1');
    }

    return substr;
  });
};

// Аналог функции `qs.stringify`, но с энкодингом значений в win1251
// (если вам вдруг нужно энкодить и ключи - тут не сложно переделать)
const stringify = (form) => {
  return Object.entries(form)
    .map(([key, value]) => (typeof value !== 'undefined' ? `${key}=${encodeToWin1251(value)}` : ''))
    .join('&');
};

// Пример отправки формы типа `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
axios.post(url, stringify({
  first: 'Первый параметр',
  second: 'Второй параметр'
}), {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
});

// Пример отправки формы типа `multipart/form-data`
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('first', iconv.encode('Первый параметр', 'win1251'));
formData.append('second', iconv.encode('Второй параметр', 'win1251'));
formData.append('someFileKey', fs.createReadStream(yourFilePath));

axios.post(url, formData, {
  headers: formData.getHeaders(),
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Помогло URL кодирование кириллицы и отправкой это axios.get

Comment: Без кода смотрится не как ответ, а как комментарий. Возможно, вы хотели прокомментировать ответ nick_n_a? Если хотите дать свой ответ -- сделайте более подробный ответ.

Comment: @AK, с тем ответом этот точно никак не связан. Вполне возможно, что это действительно ответ, только я вопрос понять не могу. Если имеется в виду, что при отправки запроса с сайта, использующего win1251, на какой-то сторонний надо вызвать `encodeURIComponent` (который, кстати, всегда энкодит в utf8), то выглядит правдоподобно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, я не знал что encodeURIComponent всегда кодирует в utf8, но перебрал кучу параметров для axios, которые советовали. В итоге просто решил кодировать строку в win1251, потом из Buffer обрабатывать hex букв и делать из этого URI строку, позже код добавлю в ответ, но решить получилось только так

Comment: Добавьте в ответ `axios.post(` и ваше новое выражение, как вы обвернули requestBody.